# Validar input con PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo una duda, ¿Cómo puedo validar dos `input` en *PHP*? El primero me debe validar solamente estos números: `00, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...` hasta el número 37. Si se ingresa otro número que no esté en ese renglón debe dar error y el segundo `input` me debe validar montos válidos de *50 en 50* hasta el 5000. Ejemplo: `50, 100, 150, 200, 250...` hasta el 5000. Si se ingresa un monto que no esté en ese renglón, como por ejemplo, `60, 75, 1575`, debe dar error.

```
if($input < 0 || $input > 37) die('Error');
if($input % 50 != 0 || $input > 5000) die('Error');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lo he resuelto de esta manera:

```
  else if(!is_numeric($input1) OR $input1 > 37){
          $errMSG = "input invalido.";
  }
  else if(!is_numeric($input2) OR $input2%50!=0 OR $input2> 5000){
         $errMSG = "monto invalido, solo se permiten montos de 50 en 50.";
```